# Can I upgrade my games edition with my friends account?

Tags: ps4, rainbow-six-siege

So I just thought about this and this is a ps4 related question: If I have a normal edition of a game on my account, and my friends account has a better edition of that said game, and I share it with my account ,and delete the normal edition game I own, will it use my friend's edition or my own?

For example:
My account has Rainbow Six Siege normal edition that runs via disk. While my friend's Rainbow Six Siege is an ultimate edition that runs without disk. Can I use the ultimate edition he owns when I activate his account as my primary on the PS4 and install the game on my own account??

Comment: The situation is that my disc is broken and cannot be used anymore, then this question popped up in my head

Comment: The only benefit from a "better" version is pre-unlocked operators. Depending on the version you have more ops to play with. On the most basic version you have to first earn Renown to buy ops with.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it will then just be your friends shared version if he ever unshares it or unlink your account you will have to either buy b the upgraded version, reinstall the regular version and purchase an upgrade, or live with the plain regular version you already own. Ps4 accounts do online checks every so often and if you are without internet I believe shared games expire in like 30 days.